# Norm computation inside a space

Tags: integration, normed-spaces, inner-products

Just want to check my solution.

Let $V$ be a vector space with the inner product $\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cdot g(x)dx$ and let:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1       & \quad 0\leq x<1\\
    2  & \quad 1\leq x<2\\
   -1  & \quad 2\leq x<3\\
  \end{cases}$$

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{5}{3}       & \quad 0\leq x<1\\
    \frac{4}{3}  & \quad 1\leq x<2\\
   -\frac{1}{3}  & \quad 2\leq x<3\\
  \end{cases}$$

calculate $\|f(x)-h(x)\|$

So I went by:
$$\|f-h\|=\sqrt{\left(\int_0^1 -\frac{2}{3}dx+\int_1^2 \frac{2}{3}dx+\int_2^3 -\frac{2}{3}dx \right)}=\sqrt{\left(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3} \right)}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)}$$
The answer is showing $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. Where have I gone wrong? Or is it correct?

Comment: Given an inner product, u*v, the derived norm is given by $||v||= \sqrt{v*v}$.  You appear to have used  calculated just $\sqrt{v*1}$ where "1" is the vector with all components 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We compute
\begin{align}
\langle f-h,f-h\rangle &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)-h(x))^2\,\mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(1-\frac53\right)^2\,\mathsf dx + \int_1^2\left(2-\frac43\right)^2\,\mathsf dx+\int_2^3 \left(-1+\frac13\right)^2\,\mathsf dx\\
&= \frac49 + \frac49 +\frac49\\
&= \frac43,
\end{align}
and hence
$$\|f-h\| = \langle f-h,f-h\rangle^{\frac12} = \frac2{\sqrt3}. $$